# strokes above an SVG for some reason

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG I made, now it has a couple of blocks that move in a straight line.

sometimes when the blocks move it just adds a stroke above them, although I have stroke disabled.
**NOTE: if you look closer you can see the orange strokes above the blocks**

[here](https://gyazo.com/7002b5cc355bbab1e69b672649e3f3be)'s what it looks like.

```css
    @keyframes move {
    0% {

        transform: translate3d(250px , 0px , 0px);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translate3d(-200px , 0px , 0px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate3d(250px , 0px , 0px);
    }
}
#loading_bar .cls-2 {
    stroke: none;

    transition: transform 2s ease-in-out;
    animation: move 4s infinite forwards;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
    <defs>
        <style>
            .cls-1{fill:#64b2c1;}
            .cls-2{fill:orange;}
            .cls-3{fill:transparent;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
            .cls-4{fill:#191919;}
        </style>
    </defs>

    <g id="background">

    <rect class="cls-1" width="1920" height="1080"/>

    <rect class="cls-2" x="871" y="769" width="90" height="84"/>
    </g>
    <g id="loading_bar">
        <rect class="cls-4" x="545" y="769" width="792" height="84"/>

        <rect class="cls-2" x="789" y="789" width="40" height="40"/>
        <rect class="cls-2" x="988" y="789" width="40" height="40"/>
        <rect class="cls-2" x="888" y="789" width="40" height="40"/></g></svg>
```

Comment: On my site, it looks fine: https://tricksfortheweb.com/svg.html

Comment: hmmm, what could be causing it then?

Comment: It might just be the rendering. What OS are you using?

Comment: win10, I'm using chrome, what are you using?

Comment: Chrome on Ubuntu 16.04. Try reloading, and see what happens.

Comment: Already tried, same thing

Comment: in the code snippet it actually looks fine

Comment: In the snippet in the question, it looks fine. It's probably a problem just with your computer.

Comment: on firefox it seems to be rendering just fine? what could be the cause of that?

Comment: It's just a problem with chrome then. Also, I'm using chrome on win8, not ubuntu... forgot which computer I was using :)

Comment: lol how can you even forget that

Comment: I'm used to using my Ubuntu computer, but I'm using this one for the time being because the Ubuntu one is dead. I just forgot.

Comment: Working fine here too on Chrome / Win 10. Almost certainly an odd rendering thing. Could try `transform:translateZ(0);` or `overflow:hidden;` on the parent (as I see you have it already on the containers)

Comment: Ill definitely try it! thanks!

Comment: didn't work, but if it's only a bug on my computer. then it's fine